# Graphviz: make invisible node take no space

Tags: graphviz

Consider the graph

```
digraph "Graph b9ca21a1-971e-400c-a7f4-cd650986476a" {
    graph [ margin=10 ];
    node [ shape=point ];

    "Invisible"  [
        //height=0,
        //width=0,
        //margin=0,
        //style=invis,
        color="red"
        ];

    subgraph "cluster_1" {
        "A";
        "B";
        "Invisible";
        "C";
        "D";
    }

}
```

resulting in

[image: image1]

I want the red node to be completely invisible, taking up no space, but it has to remain there, such that it can be used for `lhead`/`ltail` an other such miscellaneous things.

When uncommenting the commented lines, the result is

[image: image2]

As you see, there is still a spatial artifact of this node.

Question: is there a way to remove this completely, without affecting the other nodes' layout in the graph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [nodesep](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#a:nodesep) to minimize the node separation (min is 0.02) and instead add invisible [peripheries](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#a:peripheries) to the visible nodes in order accomplish an approximately equal separation of them.

Here's an example of how to transform an approximation of your first graph into an approximation of the second:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/viz.js@1.8.0/viz.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-graphviz@0.1.2/build/d3-graphviz.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph" style="text-align: center;"></div>
<script>

var dots = [
    `
digraph "Graph b9ca21a1-971e-400c-a7f4-cd650986476a" {
    graph [ margin=10, nodesep=0 ];
    node [ shape=point, peripheries=3, penwidth=0 ];

    "Invisible"  [
        //height=0,
        //width=0,
        //margin=0,
        //style=invis,
        color="red"
        ];

    subgraph "cluster_1" {
        "A";
        "B";
        "Invisible";
        "C";
        "D";
    }

    "X" [color="blue"];
    "X" -> "Invisible" [headclip="false"]
}
    `, `
digraph "Graph b9ca21a1-971e-400c-a7f4-cd650986476a" {
    graph [ margin=10, nodesep=0 ];
    node [ shape=point, peripheries=3, penwidth=0 ];

    "Invisible"  [
        peripheries=0,
        height=0,
        width=0,
//        margin=0,
//        style=invis,
        color="red"
        ];

    subgraph "cluster_1" {
        "A";
        "B";
        "Invisible";
        "C";
        "D";
    }

    "X" [color="blue"];
    "X" -> "Invisible" [headclip="false"]
}
    `
];

var dotIndex = 0;
var graphviz = d3.select("#graph").graphviz();

function render() {
    var dot = dots[dotIndex % dots.length];
    var transition1 = d3.transition()
        .delay(1000)
        .duration(1000 + 4000 * dotIndex);
    graphviz
        .tweenShapes(false)
        .engine("dot")
        .dot(dot)
        .transition(transition1)
        .render();
    dotIndex += 1;

    transition1
      .transition()
        .duration(0)
        .on('end', function () {
            if (dotIndex != dots.length) {
                render();
            }
        });
}

render();

</script>
```

Comment: The downside of this approach is that any edges will only go as far as the outermost periphery, which looks ugly.

Comment: What is the error message and which browser version are you @using?

Comment: Chrome {
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}

Comment: I've updated the answer to use headclip="false" to let edges go to the center of the node and added an edge from a blue dot to show it.

Comment: ...and tailclip=false for the tails. Good catch!